# solve for $x$, $(\sqrt{a+ \sqrt{a^2-1}})^x+(\sqrt{a- \sqrt{a^2-1}})^x=2a$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, exponentiation

Find the value of $x$ when $$(\sqrt{a+ \sqrt{a^2-1}})^x+(\sqrt{a- \sqrt{a^2-1}})^x=2a.$$See, by hit and trial method it is clear that $x=2$ is a solution. But I failed to solve this explicitly to get the solutions.
My Attempt: \begin{align*} &(\sqrt{a+ \sqrt{a^2-1}})^x+(\sqrt{a- \sqrt{a^2-1}})^x=2a \\ \implies \> & (a+ \sqrt{a^2-1})^{x/2}+(a- \sqrt{a^2-1})^{x/2}=2a\\ \implies \>& (a+ \sqrt{a^2-1})^x+(a- \sqrt{a^2-1})^x+2(a+ \sqrt{a^2-1})^{x/2}(a- \sqrt{a^2-1})^{x/2} = 4a^2.\end{align*} I have no idea how to proceed after this. Also I tried by multiplying conjugate up and down, but I failed. Please help me to solve this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about $x=-2$?

Comment: @Angina Seng. Yes $x=-2$ will also work. But it also by hit and trial method. I am stucking with the exact explicit solution for $x$.

Answer (score 4):

put $u=(\sqrt{a+ \sqrt{a^2-1}})^x$

then taking conjugate,$\frac{1}{u}$=$(\sqrt{a- \sqrt{a^2-1}})^x$
or we have to solve

$u+\frac{1}{u}=2a$ which can be easily solved.

Comment: Sorry, I evidently haven't learnt it yet: what do you mean by a conjugate in this case? I have only seen it used so far with complex numbers.

Comment: @A-levelStudent   consider $u=(\sqrt{a+ \sqrt{a^2-1}})$ multiply numerator and denominator  of this by $(\sqrt{a- \sqrt{a^2-1}})$,you get  the reciprocal

Comment: and that's called a conjugate?

Comment: yes it is used to eliminate radicals , commonly used for rationalising denominator

Comment: Yes, I understand the algebra just fine, thanks, it's just the terms or notation that prevent me from knowing many new topics I haven't covered yet :)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint :** Let $y=a+\sqrt{a^2-1}$. The equation you have to solve is equivalent to
$$y^{x/2} + \frac{1}{y^{x/2}} = y +\frac{1}{y}$$